# Setup React native firebase Crashlytics without google-services.json(iOS and android)

Tags: firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I am not able to connect react native app with Firebase Crashlytics with default initialisation code without `google-services.json`.

The main intention is to fetch clientId, appId, apiKey, storageBucket, projectId, etc from our backend server(same key like json) is let's say in future if firebase account will change then no need to upload new app to google play/App Store.

Used below code in **App.js**:-

```
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';

const credentials = {
            clientId: '',
            appId: '',
            apiKey: '',
            databaseURL: '',
            storageBucket: '',
            messagingSenderId: '',
            projectId: '',
          };
await firebase.initializeApp(credentials);

console.log(`Fire base initialised successfully`);
```

able to see this message like "Fire base initialised successfully"

But when I am trying to import crashlytics in app like

```
import crashlytics from '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics';
```

then getting following error

> [Wed Jul 19 2023 18:16:10.425]  ERROR    Error: No Firebase App
> '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp() [Wed Jul
> 19 2023 18:16:10.425]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module
> AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling
> runApplication) [Wed Jul 19 2023 18:16:10.425]  ERROR    Invariant
> Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module
> (calling runApplication)

Our intention is to use import crashlytics from '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics'; without google-services.json.

Please help me in that.Thanks in Advance

Comment: without google-services.json it is not possible

Comment: But let's say if firebase account has changed may be due to billing reason then we need to again upload new app to app/play store with newly account(setup-app).

Comment: yes. you may need to change the account or setup a new account for that app.

Comment: But I think May be there will be some solution over that.

Comment: Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: there is no other way. you must need that file evertime.